# Django: checkbox values not printing to new template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a Django project that serves as a grocery store. I am trying to set it up so that when people click on checkboxes and press the confirm purchase button, then the values from the checkboxes will print to a new HTML template. The problem I am having is that when I go to the new template it doesn't print the values from the checkboxes.

Views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'

def inventory(request):
    products = request.POST.getlist('products')
    for product in products:
        a = Post.objects.get(title=product)
        a.quantity = a.quantity -1
        a.save()
    print(products)
    return render(request, 'blog/confirm.html')
```

Home.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'inventory' %}" method="POST" id="menuForm">
      {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.quantity > 0 %}
            <article class="media content-section">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2">{{ post.category }}</a>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" >{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
                <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="product_{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.title }}" form="menuForm" name="products" > Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
              </input>
              </div>
            </article>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" form="menuForm">Confirm Purchase</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

confirm.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2">{{ post.category }}</a>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" >{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
            <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="product_{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.title }}" form="menuForm" name="products" > Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
          </input>
          </div>
        </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
path('list/', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
path('confirm', views.inventory, name='inventory'),
```

[image: confirm.html]

Comment: on confirm.html page data is comming ?

Comment: @Ankit: Yes the confirm.html shows the nav-menu but does not display any other data. I will add a picture for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of this you did not passed posts on confirm.html page

```
def inventory(request):
  posts = Post.objects.get(title=product)
  products = request.POST.getlist('products')
  for product in products:
      a = Post.objects.get(title=product)
      a.quantity = a.quantity -1
      a.save()
  print(products)
  return render(request, 'blog/confirm.html',{'posts':posts})
```

Comment: @Yahya if inventory is your PostListView instance than pass self in it and take inside your class